# Applying Sobel filter from SciPy.ndimage

Tags: python, scipy, sobel

I'm trying to apply the Sobel operator from SciPy.ndimage and replicate a result shown on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator), but the images are very different.

[image: Comparison of applying the Sobel operator]

The result presented on Wikipedia shows the edges much more pronounced.

The code I'm using is listed below. Can this code be altered to agree with the result presented on Wikipedia? Original image as well as result image from Wikipedia are enclosed below.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage import filters


# Images from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator
im_original = np.array(Image.open('Valve_original_(1).PNG').convert('L'))
im_sobel = np.array(Image.open('Valve_sobel_(3).PNG').convert('L'))

# Construct two ndarrays of same size as the input image
imx = np.zeros(im_original.shape)
imy = np.zeros(im_original.shape)

# Run the Sobel operator
# See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.sobel.html
filters.sobel(im_original,1,imx,cval=0.0)  # axis 1 is x
filters.sobel(im_original,0,imy, cval=0.0) # axis 0 is y

magnitude = np.sqrt(imx**2+imy**2)

# Construct the plot

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
ax1.set_title('Original (Wikipedia)')
ax1.axis('off')
ax1.imshow(im_original, cmap='gray')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222)
ax2.set_title('Sobel operator - as shown on Wikipedia')
ax2.axis('off')
ax2.imshow(im_sobel, cmap='gray')

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(224)
ax3.set_title('Sobel operator - from scipy.ndimage')
ax3.axis('off')
ax3.imshow(magnitude, cmap='gray')

plt.savefig('sobel.png')
plt.show()
```

Images

Original Image: Valve_original_(1).PNG
[image: Original image Valve_original_(1).PNG]

Result as presented on Wikipedia: Valve_sobel_(3).PNG

[image: Result as presented on Wikipedia Valve_sobel_(3).PNG]

Comment: I don't think it's particularly useful to compare against a random image where it is uncertain how it is processed. It looks like it was just normalized to show the edges better---that doesn't mean they were using a "better" Sobel implementation or anything. The author of the image on Wiki lost their code that produces multiple images that they've uploaded, so it's likely the source isn't around anymore to compare. If anything, the images in these articles should actually be edited to provide the true results with a link to a living code repo for showing how they were generated, IMO.

Comment: I mean, it isn't even possible to know if they converted to grayscale first, or changed to L\*a\*b\* and took the L channel or something; it would be difficult to reconstruct exactly what process the author used. Better question; *why* do you want to replicate it?

Comment: This is purely a learning exercise. Is it fair to say that what I have done in the code is a Sobel filtering of the grayscale converted image, and with this information other people should be able to reproduce the result independent on the exact implementation of the underpinning algorithm?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds is correct--without knowing how the image was pre- and post-processed, it will be difficult to match the wikipedia image.  Here's one idea that gets a little closer.  If you check the histogram of `magnitude` (e.g. `plt.hist(magnitude.ravel(), bins=50)`), you'll see that it has a long tail out to a maximum of about 3.5, but most of the values are between 0 and 1.0.  If you plot `magnitude` with the large values clipped at 1.0 (e.g. `ax3.imshow(magnitude, cmap='gray', vmax=1.0)`), the plot is much closer to the wikipedia image.  (Adjust the values of `vmax` as you see fit.)

Comment: @John absolutely, your image looks like what you would expect and should be more or less exactly the same as say, OpenCV. If I did Sobel and got the Wikipedia result on a new library, I'd be worried that it was doing normalization or clipping of the values. Note, you can also try the Scharr kernel which is slightly different than the Sobel kernel, and (usually) gives a more accurate derivative approximation. [This page](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_edge_filter.html) has some of the different edge filters commonly used that are avail in scikit-image.

Answer (score 1):

To put this question to rest I post an answer based on the comments above.

The Sobel filtered image of a steam engine as shown on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) has been processed in some additional manner not specified, and can therefore not be fully reproduced. Most likely the original RGB image was first converted to a grayscale and then clamped.

Looking at the intensity histogram for the Sobel filtered image obtained from SciPy.ndiamage, see Figure below, most pixels are centred around an intensity of 3.5. Applying a clamping value of 50 produce an image closer to what is shown on the Wikipedia page.
[image: Sobel filtered image clamped to 50 with histogram]